# Why doesn't my batch script run all lines?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I want to create a batch script that will run [axis wsdl2java.bat](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/reference.html) for multiple WSDLs. When I create a batch script with just this code:

```
wsdl2java.bat
wsdl2java.bat
```

it would run wsdl2java.bat only once. I guess there is something with [wsdl2java.bat batch script](http://snipt.org/xmSo) itself.

Can someone help me figure out what is the root cause of the problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For compatibility with Microsoft's `COMMAND`, Microsoft's `CMD` has the bizarre semantic that invoking a command script within another command script terminates the invoking command script at that point.

The correct workaround for this is not the `START` command.  Nor is it invoking a subsidiary command interpreter process with `CMD` (especially erroneously using `/K` for `/C` as well).  It is — and has been for a couple of decades — [the `CALL` command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb490873.aspx).

```
call wsdl2java.bat
call wsdl2java.bat
```

Comment: thx for the answer, as well as for explanation. Works for me. As soon as I get some rep, I will vote it up also (:

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer. I also bow before your SUPERIOR knowledge, yet feel strangely offended by your tone. But hey, whatever floats your boat.

Comment: The /C is still a valid method, just not preferred anymore.  Deprecated, but still functional...

Comment: No, M. Knoblauch.  Using a subsidiary command interpreter will prevent any environment changes made in the script from taking effect in the originally invoking command interpreter, which is the usual effect when the script is invoked directly.  Both `START` and `CMD /C` differ in operation from `CALL` in ways that mean that they aren't what's wanted in such circumstances as these.

Comment: @JdeBP: Was `call` part of MSDOS? Or was that part of DRDOS?

Comment: You're probably thinking of [`INSTALL` in `CONFIG.SYS`](http://drdos.net./documentation/usergeng/09ugch9.htm#1323), which was a PC-DOS version 4 innovation.  `CALL` is a built-in command in the command interpreter, and not an operating system thing at all.  It's been in `COMMAND` since the version of `COMMAND` that came with MS-DOS 3.3.  It's in Microsoft's `CMD` because `CMD` continues the bizarre semantic of `COMMAND` with respect to nested scripts.

Comment: @Nils:  Both.  The CALL command was available in MS-DOS v3.1 ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/34768 ), and as I recall DR-DOS introduced it first (I don't remember which version though).  Before the CALL command was available, we had to use "Command.com /C name_of_target_batch_file.bat" for which the main disadvantages were that this consumed valuable RAM, loading TSRs would lead to instability after processing of the target batch file had completed, any altered environment variables would be lost, etc.  The CALL command resolved all these problems well.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, Windows switches completely to the new batch file when you start it from within another batch file and does not return.

The workaround would be to execute

```
start wsdl2java.bat
```

-- again, just from the top of my head. I could not find a reliable source in my short google research.

Update: as JdeBP pointed out, mine is the <strike>old</strike> wrong way. It may have been too obvious that I have not touched the innards of MSDOS or Windows CMD-shell or whatever it's called these days for some decades.

Update2: jeez, I said "off the top of my head".

Comment: Yeah, back in the MSDOS days, that was the case.  I'm not sure if that is still the case though. . .

Comment: I didn't say that it was old, although it is in fact _almost_ as old as `call` — `start` dating from approximately 1987.  I said that it was **wrong**.  Think carefully about what `start` _actually does_ and compare and contrast that with what the questioner wants to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cmd.exe /k filename.bat` to launch each batchfile.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4036937/6635520),also it depends on your commands that is inside. for example if we call npm script inside of it we should run script with call command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).